# Invalid hook call.Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper))>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import FileBase from "react-file-base64"
import useStyles from "./styles";


const Form = () =>{
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({ creator: '', title: '', message: '', tags: '', selectedFile: '' });
    const classes = useStyles();
    const handleSubmit = () => {

    }
    const clear = () => {

    }

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.form} ${classes.root}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Creating a Memory</Typography>

                <TextField name="creator" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.creator} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })}/>
                <TextField name="title" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.title} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="message" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.message} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="tags" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.tags} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })} />

                <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                    <FileBase
                        type='file'
                        multiple={(base64) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })}
                    />
                </div>

                <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

dont know what to do  why its showing this error can someone help out.

Comment: How do you use the `Form` component?

Comment: Hey i was able to figure out the cause of error it was occuring due to wrong import instead of @material-ui/core i was suppose to import  this way @mui/material, it solved the error after importing like this